# What's the shortest code to generate the below matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

My 1st post - Just started learning R and I am trying to generate the below matrices using the shortest code possible and can only think of the long/manual way. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is probably better for code golf, but here's my attempt:

```r
n <- 5
m <- diag(n)
-((row(m) + col(m) -2) %% n)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4
#> [2,]   -1   -2   -3   -4    0
#> [3,]   -2   -3   -4    0   -1
#> [4,]   -3   -4    0   -1   -2
#> [5,]   -4    0   -1   -2   -3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A similar route:

```
n <- 5
v <- seq_len(n)
-((outer(v, v, '+') - 2) %% n)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly short version, but probably not the shortest:

```
n <- 5
-matrix(matrix(1:n - 1, n+1, n)[-n-1,], n,n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is better suited for code golf, but I'll give it a try:

```
-matrix(floor(seq(0,29,1.2))%%5, 5)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4
[2,]   -1   -2   -3   -4    0
[3,]   -2   -3   -4    0   -1
[4,]   -3   -4    0   -1   -2
[5,]   -4    0   -1   -2   -3
```